# Square edges only on all Bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap3. How do I make all buttons, menus, navs have square corners?

I use this to make the edges square but my requirement is to have square corners only to all buttons, menus, navs of bootstrap elements to have squire corners.

```
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: You would need to make major **targeted** changes to the bootstrap CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom build would be the way to go. You need to set `@border-radius-small`, `@border-radius-base` and `@border-radius-large` to 0. You don't need Less or anything complex - do a one-off customize&download for your project from here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Those three parameters deal with most of the border radius settings... there are a few more such as for the badge. Search the page for 'radius' to find and edit these.

Comment: nice. this is the kind of answer I was looking for.